# Mathematical jeopardy with differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, biology, reverse-math

> <sup>[Jeopardy!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!) is an American television game show [...] in which
>   contestants are presented with general knowledge clues in the form of
>   answers, and must phrase their responses in the form of
>   questions.</sup>

What kind of mathematical problem is it, to ask for systems of differential equations which have a given function $x(t)$ as an (approximate) solution?

Specifically, I am looking for a simple (the most simple?) pair of differential equations

$\dot{x} = f(x,y)$

$\dot{y} = g(x,y)$

that give rise to something like an [action potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential):

[image]

To make a solution of this problem feasible, one should not fix the target function $x(t)$ too strictly, but only qualitatively:

1. **monotonously and slowly growing** – like $\alpha t$ or
   $\alpha(1-e^{-\beta t})$ – for $t \leq t_0 = 1 - \epsilon$ for some
   $\epsilon \ll 1$ and $\alpha \ll 1$, $\beta \approx 4$
2. having approximately the **shape of a narrow Gauss curve** $e^{-(x - x_0)^2/\lambda}$ for $t \geq t_1 =  1 + \epsilon$ with $\lambda\ll 1$ and $x_0
   \approx 1 + \gamma\epsilon$, $2 < \gamma < 4$
3. any **smooth continuation** from 1. to 2. (in the very narrow range between $t_0$ and $t_1$), which is also monotonously growing.

Note, that one system of differential equations giving rise to another (and biologically more realistic) kind of action potentials $x(t)$ is given by the [FitzHugh-Nagumo model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzHugh%E2%80%93Nagumo_model), but I'm looking for significantly simpler ones:

$\dot{x} = x - \frac{x^3}{3} - y + a$

$\dot{y} = bx - cy + d$

with arbitrary $a$ and appropriately chosen $b, c, d$.

Comment: Quite simple system is obtained when one is looking for traveling wave solutions for Kellr-Segel model. Moreover, the solution can be found analytically.

Comment: @Artem: Please let me know how!

Comment: @Artem: What do have traveling waves to do with my question where no spatial variables are present? And could you please give me a hint how to solve the problem analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Very often such solutions appear as a result of search for traveling wave solutions of some spatial systems. Since the form you are looking for is "impulse", it means that you are looking for a system, whose orbit has the properties $x(t)\to 0$ when $t\pm \infty$, which also implies that one particular way is to look at systems with *homoclinic* trajectories.
2. As I mentioned in the comments, one simple example is the so-called Keller-Segel model, which for the traveling wave solutions takes the form:
   $$
   \dot U=cU-\delta k \frac{U^2}{cV}\,,\\
   \dot V=-k U/c.\\
   $$
   This system can be integrated exactly (see, e.g., Model for chemotaxis
   by Evelyn F.Keller and Lee A.Segel), and for $U$ you will find something which resembles your drawing.